# Unable to update a JSON value

Tags: javascript, json

I'm writing a code where I need to filter a JSON array and update a value of a key. Here is my code.

```js
var data = [{
  "Id": "1",
  "ab": '123',
  "afb_Educational_expense_types_for_school__c": "Books or supplies"
}, {
  "Id": "2",
  "ab": '343',
  "afb_Educational_expense_types_for_school__c": "Mandatory fees"
}, {
  "Id": "3",
  "ab": '34',
}];

var itemVar = data.filter(item => item.Id == '3');
itemVar['ab'] = '22';

console.log(itemVar);
```

Here I'm trying to set `'ab' to 22` but it is not working. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: its because you try to specify a key of an object while you target an array, so you first need to target the first element of the array

Comment: [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) will always return an array.

Answer (score 2):

Your `itemVar` is an array, because `.filter` always returns an array. You have to specify that you want the first element in the array `[0]`

```js
itemVar[0]['ab'] = '22';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `findIndex` and then update the relevant item of the array:

```js
const data = [
  { "Id": "1", "ab": '123', "afb_Educational_expense_types_for_school__c": "Books or supplies" },
  { "Id": "2", "ab": '343', "afb_Educational_expense_types_for_school__c": "Mandatory fees" }, 
  { "Id": "3",  "ab": '34' }
];

let index  = data.findIndex((item) => item.Id == '3');
if (index !== -1) data[index].ab = '22';

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var itemVar = data.find((item) => item.Id == '3')
itemVar.ab = '22'
```

Thats the easiest way to solve it.

Comment: Why does everyone in all answers set numbers type to string?!

Comment: @MahbodAhmadi because it is the data structure Rakesh chose to work with?